How to fix flutter crash on Samsung device when opening the app
I'm developing flutter app using the physical device Samsung, when i open the App on Samsung device my app got stuck for 1-2s then my device lock screen by itself. When i open the lock screen then i got blank screen, after a while like 2s the app is opened up.
I'm thinking if samsung has their own firewall to make my apps crashing because the permission that has to be granted for running the app because it don't happen in another android device, or anything else?

Better to add code and screenshot of the terminal and the error message that you are getting

some of error message i got:
I/SurfaceView(27668): 58429389 Changes: creating=true format=true size=true visible=true alpha=true hint=false visible=true left=true top=true z=false attached=true lifecycleStrategy=false
and
I/InsetsSourceConsumer(27668): applyRequestedVisibilityToControl: visible=true, type=statusBars I/InsetsSourceConsumer(27668): applyRequestedVisibilityToControl: visible=true, type=navigationBars @AmanpreetKaur

I/BLASTBufferQueue_Java(27668): update, w= 1080 h= 2408 ... I/BLASTBufferQueue_Java(27668): update, w= 1080 h= 2273
@AmanpreetKaur

I don't think there is something in this code, can you please post complete log with the question for better understanding

already fixed it, there's some issues with the flutter_icon lib @AmanpreetKaur

I figure it out, there's problem on implementing the flutter_icon lib to make a launcher_icon for my app. Found on github that says to deleted the mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder on android/app/src/main/res. And the crash on my samsung device when opening the app is solved too.
